# Could not click on dropdown in Safari browser on MacBook Pro

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, safari

I am new to automation and trying to click on a dropdown in my application in Safari Browser but the script fails with error.
Please Help.

**Error :**

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DHRODCLPC0316', ip: '2409:4042:2098:9614:d857:22cd:8ec8:8ceb%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities {applicationCacheEnabled: true, browserName: safari, cleanSession: true, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: true, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, version: 13605.3.8, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: C7B2C752-80D4-4453-B0C7-C35151B11F3C
```

**Configuration :**

- Safari Version 13
- Macbook Pro machine

**Flow of Code**

1. Open URL https://shop-lbs.mediatis.de
2. Login with credentials
3. Click on Quick order
4. Enter few codes to add in cart
5. Verify prices and checkout
6. Now select shipping address from dropdown

**SCRIPT :**

```
package lbs.leica;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testcase_240_UAT_SAFARI extends  ExtentReport_UAT
{
    WebDriver driver;

    public static String cardNumber = "4111-1111-1111-1111";
    public static String Expiry = "01/29";

    @BeforeTest
    public void initialization() 
    {
        test = extent.createTest("Order tests in UAT plethora of different order tests to verify tax, shipping, customer pricing, list pricing");

         driver = new SafariDriver();

         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.navigate().to("https://shop-lbs.mediatis.de");   
         System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

         reportLog(driver.getTitle());

    }

    @Test
    public void VerifyPrices() throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-menu_login_title']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='ShopLoginForm_Login'])[2]")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='ShopLoginForm_Login'])[2]")).sendKeys("fjsim@buffalo.edu");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='ShopLoginForm_Password'])[2]")).sendKeys("!InterShop00!");

            reportLog("Entered username and password");

            // Click on login in button
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='account-sign-in btn btn-primary'])[2]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            reportLog("Clicked on Login ");


            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='view-account']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            // Click on Quick Order
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='quickorder-li hidden-xs']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            reportLog("Clicked on Quick Order ");


            // Click on Copy and paste
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text()='Copy and paste'])[1]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);

            reportLog("Clicked on Copy and paste ");


            //Enter Codes in text box
            String[] voucherCodes = {"DS9800 1", "PA0515 2", "AR0222 3", "PA0027 4", "PA0571 5", "PA0813 6", "3801800 1", "3803650 1", "3800680 1", "3801815 1", "3800675 1", "3800080 1", "3800050CL 1", "3800161 1"};
            WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("addToCartCopyAndPaste_textArea"));
            for (String voucher : voucherCodes) 
            {
                input.sendKeys(voucher+"\n");
            }

            reportLog("Entered Codes ");


            //Click on Add to cart
            driver.findElement(By.id("addToCartCopyAndPaste")).click();
            Thread.sleep(9000);

            reportLog("Clicked on Add to cart ");


            //Verify and Print price
             List<WebElement> VerifyPrice  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class=' col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 list-item column-price single-price']"));

                for(WebElement price:VerifyPrice) 
                {
                    System.out.println(price.getText());  
                    reportLog(price.getText());
                }   
                    System.out.println(); 


           //Verify and Print Product                        
             List<WebElement> VerifyProduct  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='product-title']"));

                 for(WebElement product:VerifyProduct) 
                  {                 
                    System.out.println(product.getText());  
                    reportLog(product.getText());
                  }     
                    System.out.println();

                    Thread.sleep(4000);


           //Click Checkout on shopping cart page
             driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-block btn-primary']")).click();
             Thread.sleep(4000);

             reportLog("Clicked Checkout on shopping cart page ");


           //Select shipping address             

             JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;                      
             jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, 200)");
             Thread.sleep(5000);

             WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
             wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//*[@class='btn dropdown-toggle btn-default'])[2]")));
             System.out.println("Address dropdown visible");

             WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='btn dropdown-toggle btn-default'])[2]"));
             e1.click();
             Thread.sleep(5000);
             System.out.println("Address dropdown Clicked");

             wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//*[@class='dropdown-menu inner'])[2]/li[1]")));
             System.out.println(" dropdown visible");

             driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='dropdown-menu inner'])[2]/li[1]")).click();
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             System.out.println(" dropdown clicked");

             reportLog("Selected first address ");
```

Answer (score 0):

"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command."

This may indicate a bug in safaridriver. To more easily see what's going on, try passing 'safari:diagnose' capability to New Session. This will cause safaridriver to log protocol traffic to ~/Library/Logs/com.apple.WebDriver//. See `man safaridriver` for more information about enabling diagnostics.

If the protocol trace shows a command is failing unexpectedly (eg, HTTP 500), then please file an issue at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ so that it may be investigated by Apple. Including a reduced, standalone test case is super helpful for fixing issues, so please do that!

Thanks!